# return borrowed MATLAB license to Flex LM server

Tags: matlab, command-line, licensing

I am using MATLAB on a Windows 7 x64 machine, and I have successfully borrowed a license from the Flex LM server using the `lmutil.exe lmborrow` command line utility, but I am unable to return the license to the server.

I have restarted the computer, and MATLAB is not running. The following command shows which licenses are currently checked out:

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\etc\win64>lmutil.exe lmborrow -status
lmutil - Copyright (c) 1989-2010 Flexera Software, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Vendor     Feature                             Expiration
______     ________                            __________

MLM        MATLAB                              27-Nov-12 23:59
MLM        Signal_Toolbox                      28-Nov-12 00:00
```

Note that I have set my `LM_LICENSE_FILE` environment variable, so that I don't have to use the `-c` option on the command.

Now, running `lmutil.exe lmborrow -clear` says "`Clearing LM_BORROW`", but then the status command returns the same as above. That's ok, since the documentation says that the `-clear` option only prevents the software from borrowing new licenses, and that the `-return` option is the correct course of action.

But no success there. I tried the following commands, and nothing seems to do anything.

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\etc\win64>lmutil.exe lmborrow -return Signal_Tool
box
lmutil - Copyright (c) 1989-2010 Flexera Software, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
lmborrow: No such feature exists. (-5,412)

C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\etc\win64>lmutil.exe lmborrow -return MATLAB
lmutil - Copyright (c) 1989-2010 Flexera Software, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
lmborrow: No such feature exists. (-5,412)

C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\etc\win64>lmutil.exe lmborrow -return Matlab
lmutil - Copyright (c) 1989-2010 Flexera Software, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Error: Matlab not currently borrowed.

C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\etc\win64>lmutil.exe lmborrow -return MLM
lmutil - Copyright (c) 1989-2010 Flexera Software, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Error: MLM not currently borrowed.
```

I would greatly appreciate any help with returning these licenses early. Even after these borrowed licenses expire over the next two days I need to be able to borrow/return licenses reliably in the future.

Comment: Perhaps this can help you: http://www.mathworks.nl/support/solutions/en/data/1-APCO8J/index.html?solution=1-APCO8J

Comment: Thanks Dennis. I did already try this option of enabling the hidden license management UI, and after that had failed I resorted to the command line approach above in the hopes of getting more descriptive error messages.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to my question is that MATLAB license borrowing does not work properly with a triad (redundant) license server configuration.

I spoke with an IT person from my client's company who wrestled with the issue "a while ago." He said that after several attempts to fix the issue by Mathworks support, they concluded the above. Having the server reread the license file does not help. I am guessing that this is a little-used feature that doesn't justify the cost to fix.

Our solution with the client has been to caution users to borrow licenses only as long as they think they'll need to, and that has been working fine, since there are only a couple of users that need to borrow licenses to begin with (for field work).

Also, since the client has MATLAB's compiler toolbox, the client creates standalone programs, and those executables do not require a license once deployed.

It's not the most satisfying answer, but it has freed me from banging my head against the LCD screen. :)